# How to access LocalComponent.current in Composable Buttons onClick?

Tags: kotlin, android-jetpack-compose, android-jetpack, composable

I have a Button and I would like to access `LocalComponents.current` in its onClick

```
Button(onClick = {
    with(LocalRootComponent) { 
        current.doStuff()
    }
})
```

but IDE complains with

> @Composable invocations can only happen from the context of a
> @Composable function

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can access and store that object outside the `onClick` method, and then use that variable inside `onClick` , e.g.:

```
val rootComponent = LocalRootComponent.current

Button(onClick = {
    rootComponent.doStuff()
})
```